# Can I show the tag admin interface on a post when logged in as an admin?

Tags: admin, taxonomy

I have a lot of posts that I'm adding tags to, but it's annoying to have to click the "edit" link on each post to go into the admin and edit the tags. Is there a way I can embed the actual tags panel into the post itself?

Comment: Do you mean in front end of the site? Had you tried bulk edit features in admin side?

Comment: Correct, on the front end. I've tried bulk edit, but for my circumstance it's not helpful. (My post titles are long meaningless alphanumeric strings, and my list of tags is too tall to be usable in the small scrolling window.)

Comment: Maybe it easier to add a custom item to the admin bar. If you are logged in, then you have it and a edit tags link should help so. Also you don't change the theme link to edit post. A example help you, what I mean - http://wpengineer.com/2185/add-trash-button-to-wordpress-admin-bar/

Comment: Thanks - that seems like the best place to start thinking about a solution.